# cfdocument not converting Word Document to PDF correctly

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, openoffice.org, coldfusion-11

`cfdocument` in ColdFusion 11 is not converting my Word Documents to PDF correctly. I have OpenOffice 4.1.3 installed and configured in CF Admin. I am able to open the source document in OpenOffice and Export to PDF without issue. However, when I run the following code, the resulting PDF is "gobbledigook":

```
<cfdocument
    format="pdf"
    srcfile="#_tempSourceFilePath#"
    filename="#_destinationFilePath#" />
```

Here is an excerpt of the resulting PDF (the snip shows developer edition, but, the same thing happens with Standard installation):

[image]

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it is displaying the binary content, instead of rendering the file. Exactly what type of Word file (docx/2007, docx/2013, ecetera). What program created the file? Are you able to convert any Word or Excel files?

Comment: Did you restart the ColdFusion service _after_ configuring it for OpenOffice? Are there any relevant messages in the coldfusion-out.log file?

Comment: @Leigh, Not sure what program created the file. For a Word Document, I'm assuming Word. Yes, some convert fine, but a significant number come out like this.

Comment: @Miguel-F Yes, ColdFusion was restarted. In fact, after I installed the new version of OpenOffice, I restarted the entire server.

Comment: @EricBelair - Most likely MS Word, but other programs can create docx files too. Also there are different formats. Are there were any observable patterns in the documents that fail to convert? i.e. All of the failed docs are of the same type (docx/2007), or all contain certain formatting, etcetera. The only time I recall seeing that type of problem was back in CF9, but it was because OO/CF did not support the source file passed in.

Comment: @EricBelair - Can you share a sample word document file?

Comment: @ah7866 unfortunately I cannot since it contains proprietary data belonging to one of my customers

Answer (score -1):

The problem is:

```
srcfile="#_tempSourceFilePath#"
```

This is apparently the path to a binary file that is not browser-writable. A necessary condition for the *srcfile* attribute is that the file be browser-writable. That is, without the need for a browser plugin.